Unable to use browser for EC2 AWS login with inbound rule including my own IPv4
all.  I am new to AWS and have limited tech support knowledge, so please bear with me.  I recently created an AWS account for personal (not business) related reasons.  I am using EC2, and Linux for the AMI.  I am only able to connect through the browser if my inbound rules are set as

SSH TCP any IPv4
same rules for HTTP.

If I select "my IPv4" for either of these options, I am unable to connect to the instance and instead get an error message:

EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see EC2 Instance Connect Prerequisites at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-prerequisites.html.

Review of this link does not result in an obvious culprit for what I am doing incorrectly.  I likewise tried PuTTY and used the generator to change the RSA .pem to a .ppk file, but when I do this it appears to launch then asks me to "log in"? and does not look like the instance when I log in through the browser (with IPv4 set to any).  What am I doing wrong?
I am not handling any sensitive data, but it would probably be better if I did not have the IP set to any.  When I change the instance inbound rules to "any" for the IPv4, I am able to log in through the browser.  Traveling to a different location and adding a new rule for the new IP does not resolve the problem, nor does using my phone as a hot spot.  I have tried both Chrome (my default) and Edge.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.
Background: Running Windows 12.

If you wish to lock-down to one specific IP address, then you will need to use PuTTY or SSH (which is available on Windows these days, see: 3 Ways to Use SSH on Windows to Log Into Linux Server - LinuxBabe). If you are using EC2 Instance Connect, it is not possible to lock-down to your specific IP address because your SSH connection is going via the AWS service.

As mentioned in the document that EC2 Instance Connect uses specific IP address ranges for browser-based SSH connections to your instance (when users use the Amazon EC2 console to connect to an instance). If your users will use the Amazon EC2 console to connect to an instance, ensure that the security group associated with your instance allows inbound SSH traffic from the IP address range for EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT. To identify the address range, download the JSON file provided by AWS and filter for the subset for EC2 Instance Connect, using EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT as the service value. These IP address ranges differ between AWS Regions. For more information about downloading the JSON file and filtering by service, see AWS IP address ranges in the Amazon VPC User Guide.
If you are only keeping SSH to myIP address then from terminal of your local machine, you will be able to access the instance but as you are using EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT you need to add the IP range of EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT in the security group as inbound rule as well along with your IP.

I am the only one accessing the instance. I visited the site you posted and found the JSON file.  There does not appear to be an IP for us-east-2; may I use US-east-1?

There is an entry in that file for us-east-2: {"ip_prefix": "3.16.146.0/29","region": "us-east-2", "service": "EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT", "network_border_group": "us-east-2"}

Thank you, this worked.  But how did you find it?  https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json kept crashing Chrome.  In Edge, it loads a page with 67640 rows, but Ctrl-F has zero hits for "us-east-2", nor does it come up when I search that particular IP.
